# Excel 2016: Sorting pivot elements based on simple logic

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm currently trying to sort 2 variables nested in a pivot based on certain arguments.

TL;DR for some context:

(Image best explains)

[L is pivot; N is desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKAV3.png)

1. Sheet with Codes and Names attached to them - All codes have Len=4
2. Codes can be unique and have only one name attached to them. In that case I want to sort the Code-Name as being "Single"
3. Names do repeat themselves and are not individual to codes
4. A code with different multiple Names needs to be sorted as "Multiple"
5. A code with identical multiple Names needs to be sorted as "Single"
6. I have used a & and Countif to address duplicate names with a uniqued identifier

At the moment I'm quite stuck and unsure how to proceed. Based on the logic i tried 
`=IF(LEN(A4)=4,A4,IF(AND(OR(LEN(A3)=4,OR(LEFT(A4,10)=LEFT(A3,10),LEFT(A4,10)=LEFT(A5,10))),OR((LEN(A5)=4),A5="")),"Single","Multiple"))` output fails to return Single/Multiple when bullet 5.

Hope I gave enough insight. Any idea would help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you TWO different Formula. Check the Screen Shot below.

[image]

Formula 1: =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)>1,"Multiple","Single")

*This Formula is **considering the whole value** and counting the Duplicates.*

Formula 2: =IF(RIGHT(A2,1)=RIGHT(A2,1),"Multiple","Single")

*This one is **comparing 1 Character from Right**.*

**NB:** *Before apply either of the Formulas just Sort the Source Data Column.*